# LLVM API interface in LLVM-based languages?

Tags: llvm

There's quite a lot of programming languages that are based on LLVM library, most of compilers/interpreters are statically linked with LLVM as well. So it seems quite natural for those languages to expose an interface to LLVM library that is used internally. However I couldn't find any. What I want is to be able to load LLVM bitcode, modify it and save it back to file, but I want to do it in some higher level (scripting) language (not by using C++). For example it seems Julia is not exposing LLVM API at all, on the other hand Racket programming language has LLVM binding which is out of date. Is there any LLVM-based programming language that expose LLVM API to the programmer?

Comment: This question is unclear to me... do you mean you just want LLVM bindings in a different language than C or C++, or do you mean you want access to the internals of LLVM-based implementations of specific language?

Answer (score 0):

There's [`llvmpy`](http://www.llvmpy.org/):

> llvmpy is a Python wrapper around the llvm C++ library which allows simple access to compiler tools. It can be used for a lot of things, but here are some ideas:
>
> - dynamically create LLVM IR for linking with LLVM IR produced by CLANG or dragonegg
> - build machine code dynamically using LLVM execution engine
> - use together with PLY or other tokenizer and parser to write a complete compiler in Python

as well as [`ruby-llvm`](https://github.com/ruby-llvm/ruby-llvm):

> Ruby-LLVM is a Ruby language binding to the LLVM compiler infrastructure library. LLVM allows users to create just-in-time (JIT) compilers, ahead-of-time (AOT) compilers for multiple architectures, code analyzers and more. LLVM bindings can also be used to speed up Ruby code by compiling and loading computationally intensive algorithms on the fly.